# ImportError: 'Reader' cannot be imported from surprise

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-lab, recommendation-engine

After installing surprise with pip, I can't run any code.

When I try to run my first code related to surprise in JupyterLab, I get an error message related to the fact that 'Reader' class cannot be imported from surprise.

Here's the beginning of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import metrics_lib as ml
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from surprise import Reader, SVD, Dataset
from surprise.model_selection import train_test_split
```

And here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ac7f0fc68d68> in <module>
      3 import metrics_lib as ml
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 5 from surprise import Reader, SVD, Dataset
      6 from surprise.model_selection import train_test_split
      7 

ImportError: cannot import name 'Reader' from 'surprise' (unknown location)
```

I don't get it why this class cannot be automatically imported... Please help.

---

------------------ UPDATE ----------------------

I checked my PYTHONPATH and no sign of surprise.py, here is the list of what is in my PYTHONPATH:

```
>>> import sys
>>> for p in sys.path:
...     print(p)
... 

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/Users/miu/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a `surprise.py` file in your PYTHONPATH, perhaps in your current folder? That could clobber the installed `surprise` and prevent the import from working.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ronald. I just checked and no, there is no sign of any surprise.py in my PYTHONPATH... :( please see end of my post above, I just edited it with list of what is in my PYTHONPATH